# How do I place the image beneath the paragraph when I resize the browser screen?

Tags: html

So I have a paragraph on the left side of the screen and my image on the right side of the screen. It is responsive but not the way I want it to be. When I resize the browser screen, I want the picture to display beneath the paragraph i.e. I want the paragraph to be on top of the image and the image should be below the paragraph. When I try to resize the window, the image just becomes short but does not move to the next line.

I am currently using  CSS grid system to display the paragraph on the left and the image on the right. I also have the whole thing inside a container. I am also using flex box to make it responsive but that just wont help. I have also tried to use media queries but I just don't know how to tell the media query to move the image below the paragraph.

Comment: Could you post a bit of your code?

Comment: Use media queries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's as simple as forgetting the grid and flexbox and doing this.

CSS:

```
.text  { width: 50%; min-width: 20em; float: left; }
.image { width: 50%; min-width: 20em; }
```

HTML:

```
<p class="text">
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
</p>
<img class="image" src="./image.jpeg" />
```

Comment: So does it mean that if I will resize the browser window will it display it beneath the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://medium.com/@PavelLaptev/css-weekly-2-an-image-on-the-left-text-on-the-left-a5e59b2acdb5. It explains how to do exactly this.

You could also use a table but that would overcomplicate things.

(edit) To answer your question, using +Ray Butterworth's answer, yes that would mean the image would go beneath the text. (Or, vice versa if you just switched the order of the tags.)
I put his code in a codepen with a border around the image so you can see where it would be. I tried resizing the browser and it works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwjPzP.

```css
    .text  { width: 50%; min-width: 20em; float: left; }
    .image { width: 50%; min-width: 20em; }
```

```html
<p class="text">
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
    Blah blah blah.
</p>
<img class="image" src="./image.jpeg" border="4"/>
```

Comment: @Ray Butterworth I included a codepen of your answer on my post. It works when you resize the browser window to answer +Soban 's question

Comment: Ok, so it helped me but the thing is that when the image goes below the paragraph when I resize the browser, there is a gap in the image's place but when I resize the browser, I don't want that gap and I want the paragraph to fill in the rest of the space immediately.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you could do this but I think the key lies in `width: 100%`.

Comment: I tried `text-align: justify` but that doesn't entirely solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flexbox, try using `flex-wrap`, this will force elements to the next line or 'underneath' if their max-width is reached.

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    img {
        width: 100px;
    }
    p {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="your_image.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Here is your text</p>
</div>
```